# Run django program in debug mode with virtual env in pycharm?

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm, virtualenv

I am new to django and pycharm, when i am trying to run my code with terminal everything works fine first i will activate my virtual environment and then use this command: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

But like this i am unable to go through breakpoints in the code and debug my application. Is there any command in python like above on which my code will execute on debug mode and stops on respective break points.

I also try to edit my configure but that didnot workout, can you also guide me where i have to place my virtual coomand in this to activate virtual environment during debug mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your `python interpreter` to `your_venv_path/bin/python` and change your `working directory` to `your_project_path`

Comment: python interpreter is a drop down i can only choose that. And change the working directory. After doing these changes i am not even able to deploy it on local server due to  virtual environment is not active.

Comment: go to pycharm settings and search `interpreter` and add your python virtualenv to pycharm interpreter list.
i prefer to you that create your `venv` inside of project directory and ignore from git and docker (if you are using docker).